# Displaying wordpress gallery images src in Gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using Gutenberg default post editor to edit my WordPress posts.

I have tried serval approaches to display the post's gallery, but none of them worked.

```
     <?php
    var_dump($_GET['id']);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    $gallery = get_post_gallery( $_GET['id'] /* The post ID from $_GET */, false );
    // Loop through all the image and output them one by one.
    foreach ( $gallery['src'] AS $src ) {
                ?>                
                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="Gallery image" />
        <?php
    }
      ?>
```

Debugging notices:

```
string(3) "404"


Notice
: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
/home/mialuzco/domains/mia-luz.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/mia luz/page-gallery.php
on line
23


Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/home/mialuzco/domains/mia-luz.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/mia luz/page-gallery.php
on line
23
```

Basing on this [piece of knowledge](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery/) I should have got it worked by now, but nothing really works..

How can I display post gallery images src?

**EDIT**

[My post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5WE9.jpg)

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get errors on the screen or your logs?

Comment: @LajosArpad https://mia-luz.com/gallery/?id=404 - This is the errors

Comment: ```$gallery['src']``` is a boolean value rather than a collection. How is it initialized?

Comment: @LajosArpad according to the link I have shared, it suppose to be an array of src attribute. Either way, I haven't found any solution to approach it correctly, I have searched online for few hours probably

Comment: Yotam, the error tells you that ```$gallery['src']``` is of type ```bool```. That's your problem. I cannot help you further if you do not show me how ```$gallery``` and ```$gallery['src']``` was initialized.

Comment: @LajosArpad https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/eYzQpWV - This is the entire code.. There is no initialization, I'm receiving the post ID using `$_GET`, and reaching out to the same post using his ID to lure the gallery out.
Also I made sure that the same post has gallery inside.

Comment: Please do a ```var_dump``` for ```$_GET``` and see if it contains an ```id```.

Comment: @LajosArpad it seems boolean value notice comes from there, but I don't understand why. I updated my question

Comment: Again. What is the exact value of $_GET['id']?

Comment: @LajosArpad `?id=404` -> the id

Comment: Again. Please tell me what the value of $_GET['id'] is.Is it indeed 404? You need to actually try and test this via ```var_dump( $_GET['id'])```.

Comment: @LajosArpad I updated the question previously, the output is `string(3) "404"`. when I `echo $_GET['id'];` I receive `404`, it's working fine I think.

Comment: Okay. Next, we will need to find out what is the exact boolean value you get.

Comment: Can you ```var_dump(get_post_gallery( $_GET['id'] /* The post ID from $_GET */, false );)``` ?

Comment: @LajosArpad Return `bool(false)`, How can it be? the gallery exists..

Comment: Do you have a post having the id of 404?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, please watch the edit I have made.

Comment: Understood. Can you load anything else from the database around the place where you are attempting to load the gallery? Maybe your database connection is not initialized at the point where you try to load data from the database.

Comment: @LajosArpad If I use `$post->post_content` it prints the entire post including the gallery. but I need only the gallery

Comment: I have also tried using this https://gist.github.com/BinaryMoon/cd1eb239d4a14ba3ab45b756e4c64828 
Did not worked.

Comment: Very strange behaviour.

Comment: @LajosArpad Got it working! removed the `if($gallery_prefix)` from the github I sent you, because it returns false for some reason and it worked!

Comment: Do you mean that you have removed ```if ( $prefix_gallery ) {```?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, my bad, but It worked.. I have no idea yet why it return boolean false value.